# lapply on text files to make one single data frame in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have few text files which are named as follows:
abc.txt, def.txt and so on(just showing 2 text files here)

`abc`.txt has following lines in it:

```
ID  Inc
1   0.3
2   -0.2
3   0.45
4   0.12
```

and `def`.txt looks like this:

```
ID  Inc
2   0.13
5   0.11
6   0.43
```

I want to have final output data frame like this:

```
abc 0.3
abc -0.2
abc 0.45
abc 0.12
def 0.13
def 0.11
def 0.43
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
files <- list.files(path = baseDir, pattern = "*.txt",full.names = TRUE,
                    recursive = FALSE)
lapply(files, function(x){
  a = basename(x)
  a = gsub("\\..*","",a)
  df <- read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep ="\t")
  df$type <- a
  newDF <- data.frame(df$type,df$IncLevelDifference)
})
```

Since I am applying lapply, I am getting that many number of dataframes(as the number of input files). Also I want to combine it into one data frame(for downstream analysis, so I hope this newDF is available somehow outside the lapply loop) with or without the presence of headers in final output dataframe. I can add the column names separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `files`-vector like this:

```r
#> files
#> [1] "abc.txt" "def.txt"
```

You could use `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)

files %>%
  `names<-`(., gsub("\\..*", "", .)) %>% 
  map_df(~ read.table(., header = TRUE, sep ="\t"),
         .id = "ID")
```

which returns

```r
   ID   Inc
1 abc  0.30
2 abc -0.20
3 abc  0.45
4 abc  0.12
5 def  0.13
6 def  0.11
7 def  0.43
```

The first two lines create a named vector

```r
#>       abc       def 
#> "abc.txt" "def.txt"
```

The function `map_df` uses this vector as input and returns a data.frame after the function inside of `map_df` has been executed. The elements of the named vector are used as first argument of the `read.table()`-function. This function returns a data.frame like shown in your question, but `map_df`'s `.id = "ID"` argument replaces the `ID` column with the name stored in the named vector.

Comment: @akrun I think downvoting is okay, if the answer is bad. But your answers don't fall into this category... I learnt a lot from your answers. Please undelete your answer since it is a valuable contribution for this question and the people learning `R`.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the code? this package is new to me

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements`

Comment: I think there are missing values in your datasets? Perhaps `read.table(., header = TRUE, sep ="\t", fill = TRUE)` solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks , there was an extra tab at the end of the line in one of the file. Can you explain what `` are doing here?

Comment: `\`names<-\`` is special function, that assigns names to an object. Usally used as `names(x) <- MyVectorOfNames` which is the same as `\`names<-\`(x, MyVectorOfNames)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236164/discussion-between-user3138373-and-martin-gal).

Comment: If my text files has more than 2 columns and I need to select ID and Inc column and then perform the map_df, how can I do that?

Comment: You could use `map_df(~ read.table(., header = TRUE, sep ="\t") %>% select(ID, Inc), .id = "name")`.